# Records are missing in edit top 200 rows but can be viewed in select top 1000 rows SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to Insert new data in table using "Edit top 200 rows" and I can view Inserted data by select top 1000 rows. so far so good. But when I am trying to find (close edit 200 row window) those Inserted data in same table by selecting "Edit top 200 rows" again, those data are missing and I am not able to find them.

(p.s. But I can see those missing data in same table by select top 1000 rows though.)

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I observed that my data table rows are more than "200" and It could be a reason for that. Do I need to make any changes to default size? Tool---options---sql server object explorer and them make changes to default row values?) Please excuse me If my question is not enough clear.

I appreciate any Inputs.

Comment: It's just bringing those back arbitrarily, usually be first in.  You can change the query to do WHERE ... or change TOP 200 -- just hit the SQL button above the query in SSMS to find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit top 200 rows will do exactly that - so of course you are not going to see more rows than 200.  Edit top 200 rows is not a good way to check if data exists in a table.

That said, you can increase the number of rows visible in the "Edit Top NNN" by doing the following:

In Sql Server Management Studio:

1. Open the "Tools" menu
2. Click "Options"
3. Expand "Sql Server Object Explorer"
4. Expand "Table and View options"
5. Change the value of "Value for Edit Top  Rows Command" to the number of rows you want to appear when you edit.

If you are dealing with large tables, you are better off just doing the modifications with SQL rather than using the edit interface.

Comment: I agree Nathan, It was typo error. I am trying to add more data into same table but I am missing previously Inserted data. Now I am able to see all records. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are able to increase the number of rows viewed in the editor by going to Tools | Options, then expand the SQL Server Object Explorer node and change the 'Table and View Options' under the 'Commands' node.  The setting you want to change is 'Value for Edit Top  Rows command'.

Alternatively, you could 'Show SQL Pane' in the editor when it is showing 200 records and use an ORDER BY or WHERE clause to find the records you want to edit.